# Question regarding power consumption by a device running on electricity

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Say I have a device with resistance $R_2$, connected through a wire of resistance $R_1$ to a source providing potential difference $V$. If I close the circuit then current $I$ will flow through, and some power equal to $I^2R_1$ will be lost as heat in the wire, and the rest will be used by the device. Now, say we increase the voltage $V$ to $Vx$, but at the same time changing current to $\frac Ix$ such that the total power generated by the source remains constant
($\because P=VI$). Therefore by Ohm's law, $$(R_1+R_2)=\frac VI$$ If I need to keep power generated constant, $$\text{New } R_{equivalent}=\frac{Vx}{\frac Ix}=\frac VI x^2=(R_1+R_2)x^2$$**i.e. I increase the total resistance by $x^2$ for the same purpose**

Now I, due to some reason, have the ability to only change $R_2$ to my will, so let$$R_1+R_2y=(R_1+R_2)x^2$$$$\implies y=\frac{R_1}{R_2}(x^2-1)+x^2$$

Let $\Delta P_n$ power gained by device *from* each resister.

Getting back to resistor $R_1$, we see that on reducing current to $\frac Ix$, we get $$\Delta P_1=-(\frac Ix)^2R_1-(-I^2R_1)$$$$=\frac{I^2R_1(x^2-1)}{x^2}$$
i.e., it is now heating up by $\Delta P_1$ less, so that amount of power is used up by the device.

And in $R_2$, it was initially consuming power $I^2R_2$, now its consuming $(\frac Ix)^2R_2y$.
$$\therefore \Delta P_2=(\frac Ix)^2R_2y-I^2R_2$$$$=\frac{I^2R_1(x^2-1)}{x^2}$$

So total power gained by device is $$\Delta P_1+\Delta P_2$$$$={2\frac{I^2R_1(x^2-1)}{x^2}}$$ which is positive.

I get its graph as this:

[image]

But the dilemma is, if I take $I$, say, to be $6$ and $R_1$ to be constant(here $0.9$) then I am getting $y=60.75$ at $x=4$, which means that **if I increase voltage by $4$ times and increase resistance and decrease current accordingly, then I will gain $60.75$ power.**

But now if I increase $V$ by $4$ times, meaning decreasing $I$ by $4$ times, I can also do it by considering $I=3$ and then checking the value of $y$ at $x=2$, right? It should be the same as $60.75$ as per my understanding, but I get a different much lower value.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For fixed resistances, given Ohm's law ($V=IR$), Either $V$ is the independent variable or $I$ is the independent variable, but not both.  You can specify a new $V$, and $I$ will follow Ohm's law or you can specify a new $I$, and V will follow Ohm's law.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how that affects my problem?

Comment: In your original posting, you said "Now, say we increase the voltage V to Vx, but at the same time changing current to Ix such that the total power generated by the source remains constant ".  You don't get that option if the resistances in the circuit are constant.

Comment: resistance is being changed manually too! Please check the comment I left on Bob D's answer, the same applies here

Comment: @DavidWhite Hi David. Maybe I missed it but I don't recall the OP saying anything about altering the resistance in the original post, do you?

Comment: @BobD I agree I did not explicitly mention it but I did show the expression for change in resistance by $x^2$, after all thats where I got the final value from. you may check the edit log which i believe is public to all if you want. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: "Now I, due to some reason, have the ability to only change $R_2$ to my will, so let$$R_1+R_2y=(R_1+R_2)x^2$$$$\implies y=\frac{R_1}{R_2}(x^2-1)+x^2$$"

This was in my original post @BobD

Comment: @AltercatingCurrent Since both David and I got the same initial impression, wouldn't you agree that your post was not clear? In any case, I will be deleting my answer since it was based on the resistance being the same.

Comment: @BobD, I also note that the OP implied that the resistances were constant.

Comment: @AltercatingCurrent, you posted the equation $R_1+R_2y=(R_1+R_2)x^2$, and just before that you stated that you have the ability to only change $R_2$.  Algebraically, when you multiply $R_1$ by $x^2$, you have changed $R_1$ as well.  Your analysis is in direct conflict with your algebra.

Comment: @BobD yes I'm sorry for not making the post clear enough, it's definitely my bad

Comment: then how can I express it mathematically that a change by $y$ in $R_2$ changes $R_1+R_2$ as a whole by $x^2$? @BobD

Comment: @AltercatingCurrent This is becoming too confusing for me to follow. So I'm signing out.

Comment: @BobD alright, thanks for your time :(